ReferenceError: Amplify is not defined in javascript and cognito setup
I have a web app using javascript, lambda and cognito. I need to get the current user after sign in. I couldn't find much resource on how to get the current session info and current user.
I found the following solution on the Web and tried but it gives mainpage.html:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: Amplify is not defined.
When I search for this, I couldnt find a useful solution. How to I correct it or is there an easier way to get the current user?
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aws-sdk/2.1167.0/aws-sdk.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aws-amplify/4.3.5/amplify.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Initialize Amplify
        Amplify.configure({
            Auth: {
                // Your AWS Cognito configuration here

                // region: 'YOUR_REGION',
                region: 'us-east-1',
                // userPoolId: 'YOUR_USER_POOL_ID',
                userPoolId: 'us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx',
                // userPoolWebClientId: 'YOUR_APP_CLIENT_ID'
                userPoolWebClientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            }
        });

        // Function to get currently logged in user
        async function getCurrentUser() {
            try {
                const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
                return user;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error getting current user:', error);
                return null;
            }
        }
</script>

